# How to have nodes online but not as a separate node number?

Tags: nodes

I have several content types let say : fooCT1,fooCT2, fooCT3 ... fooCT20. 
fooCT1 has several entities to the other content types.

If I publish fooCT1 I run a rule which also publish all relevant nodes (fooCT2.. fooCt20) in order to see this information in a panel page for a anonymous user.

But using this means also that the different nodes are available under there separate names url aliases like:

/node/xx

where xx is the node nummer

How to disable this easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't disable the node entity's canonical path easily, but you can serve a 403/4 for requests to the pages instead.

The simplest method for that is probably the [Rabbit Hole](https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) module

> Rabbit Hole is a module that adds the ability to control what should happen when an entity is being viewed at its own page.
>
> Perhaps you have a content type that never should be displayed on its own page, like an image content type that's displayed in a carousel. Rabbit Hole can prevent this node from being accessible on its own page, through node/xxx.

Comment: Perfect, could not find this module ! Thxs